# Isabelle update: can I update one single lemma in an already built Isabelle session?

Tags: isabelle

I am not quite familiar with formal proof nor Isabelle, but unfortunately I am asked by my leader to work on an Isabelle project.

There is a project with multiple sessions. I can successfully build and verify this project now. My job is to change only one single lemma (which is produced by an automated model) in this project, and verify whether this change is correct and valid.

Is there anyone who can help me out? Thanks!

Definitely I cannot build this whole project from scratch because it will takes hours, and I am expected to verify such changes for many times.

I find that there is an "update" command in the manual (https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/system.pdf page 35), but I can hardly understand what this command actually does.

Can anyone please give me some suggestions? Like some other documentation, or maybe a tutorial, or a demonstrative example? Appreciate!

Comment: Is the actual lemma statement automatically produced, or just its proof?

Comment: update is definitively the wrong command. I see two options: 1) changing the lemma does not impact the rest of the proof (unlikely, but possible), then you can just change it, fix the proof and run `isabelle build` to see if it goes through. 2) changing the lemma requires changes in the rest of the theories, then you are out of luck

Comment: In case you are only required to check one lemma that is independent of the rest of the formalization, then everything is much easier: you can build the rest in a session and import it

Comment: @JoachimBreitner It's just the proof. The statement remains the same.

Comment: @MathiasFleury Thanks! It suddenly occurs to me that I can build a "dummy session" for each theory. I can use "sorry" to skip the proof part of all dependent lemmas, and make a tiny session. Each dummy session refers to a theory, and then I can verify every lemma in a much easier way. Is this a practical solution? Also by the way, is there a parser for .thy files? I am now using regex in Python, which I find not elegant at all...

Comment: If the lemma changes the same, and you just need to check the proof, you could define session that only contains all the lemmas that your lemma depends on (so that this does not get rebuild), and a session that contains just your lemma (which you rebuild after each check). No need to build the lemmas that _use_ your lemma, as the lemma statement didn’t change.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner This is also my very first thought. However, there remain two challenges for me. (1) Almost all lemmas within this project should be changed and verified one by one (independently). If I build a dependency session and an evaluation session for each one of them, it would be too redundent. (2) I would like to automate this dataset preparation process. Currently I do have an appropriate parser to deal with thy files... I am now using regex in Python, which is not elegant at all.. Could you please give me some further suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: if nearly all lemmas changes, then you need to rerun everything. So you should use `isabelle build`. Automation for generating theroy files is complicated, but maybe https://github.com/dominique-unruh/scala-isabelle (at least to have term structure, not necessarily to generate ML commands).